# Resource 'xml/file_paths' not found in AndroidManifest.xml:47, (See the Console for details) in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

As i understand the problem is that AndroidManifest.xml does not see the file_paths.xml.

file_paths.xml path

[image]

Error in console:

A failure occurred while executing \AndroidManifest.xml:47: error: resource xml/file_paths (aka com.DefaultCompany.Modsapp:xml/file_paths) not found. error: failed processing manifest.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.DefaultCompany.Modsapp"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.7" >
 
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="25"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
 
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.vulkan.version"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
        android:required="false" />
 
    <application
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" >
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.unity3d.player.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
 
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-mode"
            android:value="0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.splash-enable"
            android:value="True" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.launch-fullscreen"
            android:value="True" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.allow-resizable-window"
            android:value="False" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="notch.config"
            android:value="portrait|landscape" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.auto-report-fully-drawn"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="unity.strip-engine-code"
            android:value="true" />
 
        <activity
            android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
 
            <meta-data
                android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="notch_support"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
 
</manifest>
```

file_path.xml

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.unity3d.player.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```